# Suggesting links between Documentation articles or from Q&A to Documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

In most documentation I've consulted, there are **many** links between the different pages of the documentation. I'm aware that Stack Overflow Documentation (SOD) is to be quite different, but one thing could be really useful for someone consulting the site: *being able to navigate between questions without doing a new research every time*.

**Don't you think it would be good to add a simple way to add links to other articles on the site?**

I know you can manually create the link, but I was more thinking about a *auto-suggestion* (like tags when you ask on Stack Overflow), and a section of the article where you'd be pointed to other pages of the site. Connections like this would IMHO save a lot of the precious developers' time.

We could also imagine a feature where when you ask a question, besides the suggested existing questions, some links to SOD are provided too. Or when you answer, having ideas of links to SOD popping thanks to the keywords you type in. **What are your thoughts about this?**

---

Simple example:

When you're new to Python and reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/228/functions/932/defining-a-function-with-an-arbitrary-number-of-arguments#t=201607211250375584727) article about additional arguments in functions in Python (say you stumbled upon this when you looked up on the Internet what `**kwargs` could possibly mean), you'd be happy to find a link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/396/dictionary#t=201607211252487256953) page to learn more about dictionaries. I would be great if the author(s) of the topic/example (who probably know what they're talking about) could easily provide links as they write.

Comment: Do you mean links between for example Java Arrays and ArrayLists ? It might be a good idea for example when you want to try several libraries doing the same things in order to list the pro and cons.

Comment: @AlexiC This could be an idea, but I was rather thinking about things in Documentation articles, that you need to know about to understand the main topic. I think this would be great if an easy way of creating those links were provided. I will edit so that it is more clear.

Comment: I could see adding a "Related" sidebar like we have for Q&A... I really hate when sites interrupt me when I'm typing though, so I'd like to refrain from having links to SOD popping in any way. After I've stopped typing for a while, maybe.